# WebClient Log in website with hidden random input

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I want to login a website with WebClient.
The login-form:

```
<input id="txtID" name="txtID" type="text" maxlength="20" onfocus="javascript:setUserNameData(this);" onblur="javascript:checkUserNameData(this);" value="Tên Truy Cập" />
<input id="txtPW" name="txtPW" type="text" maxlength="12" onfocus="this.value='';setPWDXXX();" onblur="javascript:checkPWData(this);" oninput="setPWDXXX();" value="Mật Khẩu" />
<input id="hidubmit" name="hidubmit" type="hidden" />
 <input id="IEVerison" type="hidden" name="IEVerison" value="0" />
                <input type="hidden" id="detecResTime" name="detecResTime" value="" />
 <input id="detecas-analysis" type="hidden" name="detecas-analysis" value="{}" />
 <input type="hidden" name="hidServerKey" value="bong88.com" />
<input name="tk" type="hidden" id="tk" value="25af27e2101f14442f89c7f1f20f08c951c82c6f5582ae" runat="server" />
<input id="IsSSL" name="IsSSL" type="hidden" />
```

With 2 value txtCode and __tk change each time enter website.
I tried to get the source, get the values then send request to website but I failed.
Did I wrong or miss something?

Mycode:

```
 private string GetSourceForMyShowsPage()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClientEx() )
        {
            client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
            var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            string html = client.DownloadString("https://www.bong88.com/login888.aspx?IsSSL=1");
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

            string txtCode = htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("txtCode").GetAttributeValue("value", "");
            string tk = htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("__tk").GetAttributeValue("value", "");
            var values = new NameValueCollection
            {
                { "txtID", "" },
                { "txtPW", "" },
                {"txtCode", txtCode },
                { "hidubmit",""},
                { "IEVerison","0" },
                {" detecResTime","" },
                { "detecas-analysis", "{}"},
                { "hidServerKey",".com" },
                { "__tk", tk },
                { "IsSSL", "1" },
                { "PF", "Default"},
                { "RMME", "on" },
            };
            // Authenticate
            client.UploadValues("https://www.bong88.com/login888.aspx?IsSSL=1", values);
             //Download desired page

            return client.DownloadString("https://nvlai.bong88.com/sports");


        }
    }
 public class WebClientEx : WebClient
{
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

    public WebClientEx()
    {
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

I think the values between `string html = client.DownloadString("https://www.bong88.com/login888.aspx?IsSSL=1");`

and `client.UploadValues("https://www.bong88.com/login888.aspx?IsSSL=1", values);`
is different. So I failed